# Rails DateTime gives invalid date sometimes and not others

Tags: ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got a bunch of user-inputted dates and times like so:

```
date = "01:00pm  06/03/2015"
```

I'm trying to submit them to a `datetime` column in a database, and I'm trying to systemize them like this:

```
DateTime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
```

But I *consistently* get an invalid date error. What am I doing wrong? If I submit the string without `strptime` the record will save but it sometimes gets the date wrong.

Also, how can I append a timezone to a `DateTime` object?

**Edit:**

So `.to_datetime` and `DateTime.parse(date)` work for the `date` string and fail for `date2`. What's going on?

```
date2 = "03:30pm 05/28/2015"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`to_datetime`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/to_datetime):

```
date.to_datetime
# => Fri, 06 Mar 2015 13:00:00 +0000
```

Also if you read the documentation for `DateTime#strptime`, [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime). It states:

> Parses the given representation of date and time with the given
>   template, and creates a date object.

Its important to note that the template sequence must match to that of input string sequence, which don't in your case - leading to error.

**Update**

Using `to_datetime` over second example will generate

> ArgumentError: invalid date

This is because it expects the date to be in `dd-mm-yy` format. Same error will be raised for `DateTime.parse` as `to_datetime` is nothing but an api for the later. You should use `strptime` in-case of non-standard custom date formats. Here:

```
date2 = "03:30pm 05/28/2015"
DateTime.strptime(date2, "%I:%M%p %m/%d/%Y")
# => Thu, 28 May 2015 15:30:00 +0000
```

Comment: That worked for one example and failed for another? I've edited my question.

Comment: Excellent! thanks so much. I just need to figure out how to deal with bad user input now, like `0300pm 05/29/2015` or `03:00pm05/29/2015`. Any useful regex around? :)

Comment: @shivam Why has it returned year 2020 for an input of 2015?

Comment: @kaybee99 cause of my mistake. Identifier for year is `%Y` and not `%y` which was a typo. I have updated it. Thanks for pointing out. PS: `%y` is used for two digit year representation.

Answer (score 1):

```
date = "01:00pm  06/03/2015"    
DateTime.parse(date)
=> Fri, 06 Mar 2015 13:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: So that works for that string but fails for this one? `"03:30pm 05/28/2015"` any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't got your parameters in the correct order.

```
DateTime.strptime(date, '%H:%M%p %m/%d/%Y')
```

You'll also need to add `%p` for the am/pm suffix

Comment: Try now. Didn't see the pm

Comment: @CD-RUM this will work in both cases. `parse` and `to_datetime` both expect values in UK date format